# PHP Error - keep getting "Out of memory error"

Tags: php, nginx

I kept getting this error on one of the site Im working on

> Message Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

and the thing is we already set the memory limit to 512MB, and seems weird that it says allocated 2097152 which is like only 2MB?

This site is running in wordpress with woocommerce, and the even woocommerce status says the memory limit is 512MB.

Can anybody explain whats going on?

Server is running on NGINX + PHP-FPM

Comment: It sounds like you might have an infinite loop somewhere. Please show us the code where the error message is thrown, or we won't have a clue what's going on.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Are you doing anything special and getting this error.

Comment: Don't you see a path and a line number following the error?

Comment: Its throwing everywhere even in native wp files .e.g
```Fatal Error
Line 1333
Message Out of memory (allocated 6291456) (tried to allocate 114688 bytes)
File /../../.../wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php```

Comment: I could list 10-30 files showing on the log file from plugin or theme that produces this type of error.

Comment: my question here is why it says "Out of memory (allocated 2097152)" isn't that only 2MB? where as my memory limit is 512MB

Answer (score 0):

Try set `upload_max_filesize, post_max_size , max_file_uploads` and `memory_limit` in `php.ini` and then restart your Apache server. If it did not work, try to set the mentioned parameters to right on top of your code.

Best way to increase memory limit in PHP or WordPress.

> **Via php.ini file**

```
memory_limit 2048M
post_max_size 200M
upload_max_filesize 20M
max_file_uploads 20
```

---

> **Via PHP script**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
ini_set('post_max_size','200M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','20M');
ini_set('max_file_uploads','20');
```

---

> **Via wp_config.php file in WordPress**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2048M');
```

---

> **Via htaccess**

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_file_uploads 20
```

Comment: if you read my question, I mention its running NGINX + PHP-FPM

Comment: Can you please check free memeory on server please? Try this command to check `free -m` and let me know

Comment: You can also contact server provider to solve the issue related to server. They have issue solutions. They will suggest good things too.

Answer (score -1):

In wp-config file Update the memory limit according to your need

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256m');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512m');
```